# foreach loop creates a new table for each entry

Tags: php, html

What am I missing here? It always produces new tables instead of one table where all datasets are in.

```
foreach($results as $print) { ?>
    <table class='wp-list-table widefat striped'>
        <thead>
            <tr>    <!-- display table header -->
                <th style='text-align:center;' width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $character[0]; ?></th>
                <th style='text-align:center;' width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $character[1]; ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <form action='' method='post'>
                <tr>    <!-- display data -->
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $print->postleitzahl; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $print->ort; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
                <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Can you find my mistake? Sorry but I can't see it.

Comment: Because `<table class...` is in the loop.  Move it out.  And all the `<thead>` stuff and the `<tbody>` tag...  You should only have the `form` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
<table class='wp-list-table widefat striped'>
    <thead>
        <tr>    <!-- display table header -->
            <th style='text-align:center;' width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $character[0]; ?></th>
            <th style='text-align:center;' width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $character[1]; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        foreach($results as $print) { ?>
            <form action='' method='post'>
                <tr>    <!-- display data -->
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $print->postleitzahl; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $print->ort; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Haven't done it your way but it's working except the fact part of my css styling is now gone.

Comment: I think you might have to add it inside the for loop.

Comment: Ok, I don't wanna style inside HTML. I have an extra css sheet. where can I give the for loop the same class. I believe that's not possible this way is it?

Comment: You can add the style to the form. Add a class inside the form tag and copy the style from above.